# 同じセル内に２つのDataFrameを表示させたい

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebookにて、pandas.DataFrameで作成した２つの表を、
同じセル内に表示させるのは可能でしょうか。

もし可能なら、その方法を、ご教示ください。

具体的には...

以下の場合、最後のDataFrame（lst2のみ）が表示されます。

```
lst1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
lst2=[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(lst1)
pd.DataFrame(lst2)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうではなく、同じセル内に、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

あるいは、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

と表示させたいと思っています。
よろしく、お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

表示に `display()` を使用すると整った形で表示されます
(`print()` でも内容確認する程度は可能)

```py
import pandas as pd
# print(df)
display(pd.DataFrame(lst1))
display(pd.DataFrame(lst2))
```

Answer (score 0):

[28 Jupyter Notebook Tips, Tricks, and Shortcuts for Data Science](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) から引用します。

> #### 2. Pretty Display of Variables
>
> What is known less, is that you can alter a modify the ast_note_interactivity kernel option to make Jupyter do this for any variable or statement on its own line, so you can see the value of multiple statements at once.
>
> ```
> from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
> InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
> ```

[image: display]

Answer (score 0):

```
matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show
```

を利用する方法もありました。

```
import pandas as pd

lst1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
lst2=[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1=pd.DataFrame(lst1)
df1.plot()
plt.show()

df2=pd.DataFrame(lst2)
df2.plot()
plt.show()
```